# matrix calculations matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 3x3 matrix as follows

```
ls        1      2     3
mic  1    d11    d12   d13
mic  2    d21    d22   d23
mic  3
```

where the matrix elements define distance between each component e.g. d11 is the distance between microphone 1 (mic 1) and loudspeaker 1 (ls 1).

each ls has a a specific gain value as follows 3x1

```
g1     // ls1
g2     // ls2
g3     // ls3
```

How would I divide each gain value to the corresponding elements within the distance matrix e.g. g1/d11, g1/d21 and g2/d12 ,g2/d22  etc and then store the values within a results matrix.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

use `bsxfun`

```
res = bsxfun(@rdivide, gain_vec(:)', dist_matrix);
```

Comment: it's enough calling just `bsxfun(@rdivide, gain_vec', dist_matrix)`

Comment: @fpe, since the matrix is square I wanted to make sure the division is carried out on the proper dimension - never too careful with these things...

Comment: you are right, you posted the answer in the meanwhile I was checking the two ways, asserting that both lead to the same results.